# Set JSON as data source for list view in Android app

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I used a list view in my Android app, I populated it with string array values, it worked! But when I tried with JSON content, with a class, using name and code as data members in the class. Here is my code:

```
 private void fillListView() {

    ListView mainListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<Planets> listPlanetsClassAdapter;
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_Details);
    String[] planets = new String[]{"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
    String[] planets1 = new String[]{"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Planets> planetLISTJSON= new ArrayList<Planets>();
    Planets obj_Planets = new Planets();
    planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(planets));

    // JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(planets));
    for ( int i=0;i<planets1.length;++i)
    {
        obj_Planets.code=12;
        obj_Planets.name="My Gola";//planets1[i];
        planetLISTJSON.add(obj_Planets);
    }

    // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items.
    // Otherwise an exception will occur.
    listAdapter.add("Ceres");
    listAdapter.add("Pluto");
    listAdapter.add("Haumea");
    listAdapter.add("Makemake");
    listAdapter.add("Eris");
    //mainListView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    mainListView.setAdapter(listPlanetsClassAdapter);
}
```

```
public class Planets {
   public String name;
   public int code;
}
```

Comment: wow - you really should edit this question.. i don't event get what the real problem is.. what are you observing right now?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + A will give a pop-up. Type "reformat" and see what the other keyboard shortcut is

Comment: 1) You have no JSON here. You have what is called a POJO. 2) This code doesn't compile. `listAdapter` declared but not initialized

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom adapter which extends the `ArrayAdapter` and override the method `getView()` to return your own view that contains the contents that you want to display.

For example,

**UserAdapter.class**

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
       super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position
       User user = getItem(position);    
       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
       }
       // Lookup view for data population
       TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
       TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHome);
       // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
       tvName.setText(user.name);
       tvHome.setText(user.hometown);
       // Return the completed view to render on screen
       return convertView;
   }
}
```

**Use custom adapter**

```
// Construct the data source
ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
// Create the adapter to convert the array to views
UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
// Attach the adapter to a ListView
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can see more details [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)